# "Navigate to" windows phone 8.1 sdk

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

When I used windows phone 8 SDK, I could right click on a text block and choose the option "navigate to" and select the page I want to navigate to when its pressed

but now I don't have the "navigate to" option in windows phone 8.1 SDK. How can I navigate in windows phone 8.1 sdk

Answer (score 1):

This feature is not available in windows Phone 8.1(windows RT version) But available in windows phone 8.1 Silverlight

you can easy navigate/open any view page through solution explorer!